# migrate question to Apple exchange

Tags: support

this is probably better suited to the Apple exchange.  i asked on EE because the question tends towards investigating the hardware and software design considerations of Apple's USB support.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/83442/ipad-usb-flash-drive-file-transfer/83443#83443

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get a question migrated is usually to flag the question for moderator attention. If your migration target is anything besides superuser, it will require a moderator.